# How can I delete files over (n) days old but leave (n) files regardless of age?

Tags: linux, shell, find, ls, unix-head

I wrote the following in PHP but I was wondering if there is an elegant way to do this in a Linux shell script? Basically delete files over (n) days old, but leave the (n) newest files regardless of age.

```
    PHP

    foreach (glob("backup/*.db") as $file) {
        $a[$file]=date("Y-m-d",filemtime($file));
    }
    $i=0;
    arsort($a);
    foreach($a as $file=>$date) {
        if ($i++>=10) {
            if ($date<=date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-10 days"))) {
                unlink($file);
                xmessage("PURGED: $file");
            }   
        }   
    }
```

My idea was to delete with "find -mtime +(n) exec rm" but only pipe in the files that are NOT in "head -n +(n)"? But "head -n" does not seem to do what I thought it would. Thanks.

```
SHELL SCRIPT

find -mtime +10 | ls -t *.DB.tar.gz | head -n -10
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this using all GNU find, sort, awk, and xargs:

```
find . -type f -printf '%Ts %p\0' |
sort -k1,1nr -sz |
awk -v days=10 -v cnt=10 '
    BEGIN { RS=ORS="\0"; secs=systime()-(days*24*60*60) }
    (NR>cnt) && ($1>secs) { print gensub(/\S+\s+/,"",1) }
' |
xargs -0 ls --
```

Change `ls` to `rm` when you're done testing and sure it's giving you the expected output.

Comment: I would like to mark [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358865/remove-all-files-older-than-x-days-but-keep-at-least-the-y-youngest) question as a duplicate, but not a single answer seems correct. This answer actually belongs there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I guess it'd be better if we can explain all those options and awk commands as probably not everyone can understand those..

Comment: @LamLe no, it's not necessary to explain every language construct used in every tool tagged in a question, If there's anything in my answer that someone doesn't understand a quick glance at the man page will fix that.

Comment: It must be `$1<secs` but not `$1>secs`. Otherwise this will delete newer files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a version of `find` that cannot use `-printf` (f.ex. `busybox`), you can use this:

```
find ${FOLDER} -type f -exec stat -c "%y %-25n" {} \; |
sort -n |
head -n -$(MIN_FILES_TO_KEEP) |
cut -d ' ' -f3- |
xargs -r -I FILE find FILE -mtime +$(MIN_DAYS_TO_KEEP) |
xargs -n1 rm
```

I had to refactor the command to use in `docker-compose` and this was the result. It is not the most elegant or efficient solution though.